# How to access nested dict wihtout multiple .get() and nested_lookup inPython3?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have nested dict which values I want to replace. I can't use nested_update/nested_lookup due to the structure of the keys resulting to wrong updates as there are multiple same keys but differently nested. E.g. if there are multiple keys Z with different "prekeys" they will get all changed by nested_update which I don' want.

So basically what I want to do programmatically is:

`extracted_event.get('X').get('Y').get('Z') = "anything"`

`listA = ['X','Y','Z']`

I have a for loop which checks if there is a subkey X, Y and Z by presaving the subdict:

```
to_replace = extracted_event
for element in listA:
       try:
         to_replace = to_replace.get(element)
         
       except AttributeError:
         print("Key not existing, nested dict has no nested dict with this key")
         continue
```

This way I can check and get the value of a nested dict (or it's key).
How can I update the Value as in the first line + in the original dict since I'm just presaving a subdict?

I have simplified the example as much as possible meaning there are a lot of more keys/structured and nested dicts

Example of extracted_event

```
{'mac': ['XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX'], 'id': '7asd238dd-4b27-123123ddx-3f28198b69ab', 'hostname': 'dc', 'os': {'platform': 'windows', 'type': 'windows', 'version': '6.1', 'name': 'Windows Server 2008 Enterprise'}, 'ip': ['192.192.192.5'], 'name': 'localhost'}
```

Comment: can you give a few examples of `extracted_event`?

Comment: you should use a recursive function to deal with it or consider using [flatdict](https://flatdict.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which makes your nested dict as a flat dict with the nested keys separated by a custom separator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
import flatdict

flat_event = flatdict.FlatDict(extracted_event)

flat_event['X:Y:Z'] = "anything"

modified_event = flat_event.as_dict()
```

Comment: Thanks! I avoided flatdict as I was assuming it changes the structure (which I need to keep as I need to send back to elasticsearch in the same structure as before) :)